# Filter vue.js checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

It's my first project on vue.js and a have a problem.
I create a filter for products. Filter work only with `<input type="text" v-model="search" />`, but with checkbox don't work.
Please help.

Here's my code,

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/Lygeces4/embed/"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lygeces4/

Comment: Your jsfiddle has this error: `vue.min.js:6 TypeError: this.search.toLowerCase is not a function`

Comment: I know, so I ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better handle your search with 2 lists. One for countries and one for brends:

```
data: {
 search: { countries: [], brends: [] }
}
```

Then, update your `v-model` with :
`<input type="checkbox" v-model="search.countries"` and `v-model="search.brends"`. This way, you'll have country names in `search.countries` and brend name in `search.brends`.

Finally, you can implement the filter function this way (or another, as you wish your filters worked):

```
computed: {
  filteredItems() {
    return this.items.filter(item => {
      if (this.search.countries.length > 0) {
        return this.search.countries.indexOf(item.country) > -1;
      }
      if (this.search.brends.length > 0) {
        return this.search.brends.indexOf(item.brend) > -1;
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
}
```